# Is the Eephus pitch worth purchasing?

Tags: mlb-2k13

I'm playing as a starting pitcher in My Player Mode in MLB 2k13, and I'm to the point where I want to buy a fourth pitch to add a little diversity. My current pitches are Fastball, Curveball and Changeup, so I was thinking of adding an unusual pitch.

I noticed that I could add the Eephus pitch. Some pitchers have used this very effectively over the years and some pitchers have really whiffed with it, so I'm a little worried it won't translate well to a video game. Is the Eephus pitch strong enough in MLB 2k13 to be usable, or should I stick to something slightly more conventional, like a cutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eephus does not work well against the computer. If it is in the strike zone, there is a tendency to hit doubles and, unfortunately triples do to poor fielding, and even home runs. For a fourth pitch, I recommend 2-seam fastball or slider, something that will allow you to spin the ball from outside the zone to in, left to right or vice versa. Hope this helped

Comment: Agreed. I eventually tried it and it did not work well.